# Assigning primary key in Postgres postgis table by python

Tags: python, sql, database, postgresql, postgis

I have a table in Postgres
It has a column 'fid', which I want to use as Primary Key,

when I am doing it by python it is showing the error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UndefinedTable                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-d45be28c87fb> in <module>
      6 name_Database = 'agro_dss';
      7 sql_primary_key = "ALTER TABLE all_parameters_forecast_data ADD PRIMARY KEY (fid)";
----> 8 cursor.execute(sql_primary_key)

UndefinedTable: relation "all_parameters_forecast_data" does not exist
```

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(user='postgres', password='your_password', host='localhost', port= '5432')
conn.autocommit = True
cursor = conn.cursor()
name_Database = 'agro_dss';
sql_primary_key = "ALTER TABLE all_parameters_forecast_data ADD PRIMARY KEY (fid)";
cursor.execute(sql_primary_key)
```

but the table is there.

[image: Table]

and when I am running the same query from PG Admin, then it is working fine

```
ALTER TABLE all_parameters_forecast_data ADD PRIMARY KEY (fid)
```

[image: query run]
[image: Key added]

What am I missing in python script?

Comment: maybe try adding {database name}.{schema} in query? like ALTER TABLE agro_dss.public.all_parameters_forecast_data ADD PRIMARY KEY (fid)

Comment: @TonyTang Thanks, for the suggestion, by doing so, It throw an error,   FeatureNotSupported: cross-database references are not implemented: "agro_dss.public.all_parameters_forecast_data". But you gave the right logic. I was missing database variable here in. conn = psycopg2.connect(user='postgres', password='imd123#', host='localhost', port= '5432', dbname='agro_dss'), After adding, it worked fine.